# How can I modify a PE import table so that instead of linking to foo.dll it links to bar.dll?

Tags: windows, dll, native

I have a file `plugin.dll` whose import table links to several symbols in `foo.dll`. I want to make a new file `plugin-modified.dll`, such that `plugin-modified.dll` is identical to `plugin.dll`, except that instead of linking to these symbols in `foo.dll`, its import table imports those same symbols from `bar.dll`. Can anyone suggest a tool that will rewrite PE files in this way? Ideally command-line/scriptable and open-source, but I'm willing to consider alternatives...

(The real use case is that I want to replace the reference to `foo.dll` with `foo-unique-id-934019384.dll`, so as to be able to ship `plugin.dll` and `foo.dll` together while avoiding name collisions, just in case someone else also distributes some other plugin that links to its own, different version of `foo.dll`.

On Linux this can be done with the `patchelf` tool, and on OS X it can be done with `install_name_tool`; I'm looking for a Windows equivalent.

I'm aware that SxS assemblies may be able to solve this problem in a different way, but they have their own limitations so I want to explore both approaches before deciding.)

Comment: sounds scary dangerous. can you change it to dynamically load it using `LoadLibarary`?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a general tool that I can use to bundle up arbitrary plugins without having to make bespoke build system and source code modifications. (Specifically this is in the context of providing a general tool for people distributing Python packages on Windows -- like I said, we have standard/reliable ways of doing this exact thing on Linux and OS X already. And it's not really that scary... there's just a string in the PE import table that we want to replace with a different string.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I got so annoyed at missing this tool that I wrote it :-)

https://github.com/njsmith/machomachomangler